How to read the column of a selected excel file using Django
i have multiple header data in excel so how i can import the data in Django models
Check the image for better understanding
i am beginner at here so please dont mind my question and provide the solution please
the problem is to import the data in django models

Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! There are a few things wrong with this post which will need to be corrected before anybody can/will answer your question. First - what is your question? You haven't asked a specific question, so nobody will be able to help you answer it. What should your end result look like? What have you tried, and why isn't it working? Second - please post supporting images themselves rather than links to images.

As a side note, by a specific question, I mean that it will help us if you provide information regarding what specific data you'd like to import from Excel, and how you intend to use it in your Django models.

I will suggest you using a package name Django-excel .
Docs of django-excel https://pypi.org/project/django-excel/
